Compare a cmake list entry to an expected value
I want to compare the first element in a list and check it is equal to 1
Here is what I have tried
# Get python installation details
find_package(Python3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter Development NumPy) 
# Create a list from the numpy version
string(REPLACE "." ";" VERSION_LIST ${Python3_NumPy_VERSION})
# Get the first element
list(GET VERSION_LIST 0 MAJOR)
# Create variable
set(MY_VARIABLE "1")
# now do comparison
if (Major STREQUAL MY_VARIABLE)
    Message("Numpy OK")
else()
    Message(FATAL_ERROR "Wrong version of numpy found, please install version 1.26 upwards")
endif()

But my comparison is always failing
When output the Major variable is is 1 so I don't understand why it is failing

In CMake variable names are case sensitive. You store the value of the first element in the variable MAJOR, but compare the variable Major.

CMake has an "version triplet" comparison. Use that instead. See: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#version-greater-equal

It was a misunderstanding of CMake variables
I had used Major instead of MAJOR
